# Prevent FileSystemWatcher path rename

Tags: c#, file

I am using a FileSystemWatcher in my code to track any change/rename/addition of file under the monitored path. Now, I need to put a constraint on the monitored path (**directory location**) so that it cannot be renamed or deleted. With the FileSystemWatcher whenever the monitored path is renamed the reference changes automatically. I tried to add:

```
DirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule( 
        new FileSystemAccessRule(User, 
                                 FileSystemRights.ReadAndexecute), 
        AccessControlType.Allow)
```

....but that is not helping. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

Comment: So your question isn't about FileSystemWatcher at all?

Comment: https://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/ you can use this technique for applying special permissions for watched directory

Comment: What about setting appropriate permissions to directory? It's OK, when admin decides, what can be removed/renamed here. It's not OK, when the same does some 3rd party software.

Comment: Apply NTFS security to the folder from Windows Explorer. Job done

Comment: Bear in mind that renaming and moving a specific directory are actions taken against the *directories in which that specific directory does/will appear*, not actions taken against the directory itself.

Comment: The FileSystemRights.Delete is not working properly as the directory can still be deleted. And the watcher is somehow not working also when all these Access controls are set on the directory.